# Adding functionality to onClick in Android

Tags: android, button, onclick, overriding

I want to run a function each time a button is pressed in my app. I know I can make a new button which extends Android's button and override `onClick()` but I have already made my entire app and want this new functionality as an afterthought. Can I somehow add this functionality without changing the class of all buttons in my app?

Lets say I want to add something like

```
runthisfunction();
```

before every `onClick()` code executes. There are many buttons in various activities and so they have their own onClick functions.
Is there a way that this function is run before each and every `onClick()` without the need to make a new class and changing all the existing buttons.

Comment: please share your button code

Comment: You need to explain/show what you have better. You want to add functionality to onClick. In `onClick()` add the functionality...done

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. You're not going to override `onClick` and nullify the functionality of all your other buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your xml resource for whatever button/view you want to have an onClick listener:

```
android:onClick="fncClick"
```

For example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="fncClick" />
```

Then in the activity that utilizes that xml resource, include:

```
public void fncClick(View view) {
    //TODO: Code here
}
```

This ONLY attaches an onClick listener for this specific button - not all buttons